# GoLang, bad readout from slice

Tags: api, go, slice, mux, gocql

Im pretty new in GoLang and i need some help. Im making simple API app.

pasing structs by API to slice looks like this:

```
type Struct struct {
    //some records
}

var structs []Struct //slice

func SetStruct(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var st Struct
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    decoder.Decode(&st)
    emails = append(structs, st)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(structs)
}
```

And that function works ok.

Second thing i want to do, is to deleting that structs from slice depends on `NR` parametr. I call it `POST`. Method looks like this:

```
func SendStruct(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var st Email
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    decoder.Decode(&st)
    for i, item := range emails {
        if item.NR == st.NR {
            structs = append(structs[:i], structs[i+1:]...)
            //if numbers match, delete from slice emails
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(emails)
}
```

And it works pretty ok when i have scenerio like (for example):

```
{"NR": "22"}
{"NR": "33"}
{"NR": "22"}
```

When i want to delete `"33"`, it works pretty ok. When i want to delete `"22"` (both of them) things starts to be complicated, because when i pass `22`, app crashes.

In `item.NR` (from `SendStruct`) i get variable out of range. When i add `break` paarmetr in `for`, it works ok but i can only deleting structs one-by-one. I want to delete all `22` in one API call. Error that i get:

> http: panic serving [::1]:52163: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify slices while you're iterating over them. The `range` doesn't know that the slice is now shorter than it was when it started, so eventually it tries to iterate beyond that point and -- whoops! -- there's no more slice to be found.

What I'd recommend doing instead is keeping a separate slice with a list of indexes where the item to be deleted can be found. Then, when you're done iterating over the email slice, you can iterate over this index-tracker slice and delete the relevant items. Make sure you sort the index-tracker slice so that it goes from high indexes to low indexes or you'll end up shortening the slice relative to where the remaining index points are.

Comment: I get it,so when (for example) i have 5 structs in array, i deleting third, and it goes away from range, because it tries to get into 5th but after deleting third, slice is range of 4 not 5?

Comment: @michasacuer exactly.

Comment: And alternative option is to use the 3-part for loop style `for i := 0; i < len(data); i++`.  Len is checked and on each iteration and thus captures the updated index.  That all said, altering the slice while iterating isn't actually what's breaking your code.  You're iterating over the slice `emails` but using the index variable to index and subslice `structs`.  And this works fine as long as you're only ever cutting one thing out of `structs`, but once you're cutting more than one (and it's at the end), your emails slice is now longer than structs and panics.